# Some problem in package my code into class

Tags: python, class, scipy-optimize-minimize

My code:

```py
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np

class Least_squares:
    def __init__(self):
        self.d = 2           #decision_demension
        self.parameter_sets = np.ones(6)       #Parameters_sets = 1+1 +d+ d (alpha+ beta_0 +...+...)

    def func(self,x):
        parameter_sets= self.parameter_sets
        alpha = parameter_sets[0]
        Phi = parameter_sets[1]
        T = 1
        for i in range(2, self.d + 2):
            Phi += x[:, i - 2] * parameter_sets[i]
        for j in range(self.d + 2, len(parameter_sets)):
            Phi += x[:, j - self.d - 2] * x[:, j - self.d - 2] * parameter_sets[j]

        Phi += alpha * T


        return Phi

    def Euclidean_distance(self,a, b):
        dis = 0
        for i in range(self.d):
            dis += (a[i] - b[i]) ** 2
        return dis ** 0.5

    def residuals(self, y, x):
        parameter_sets = self.parameter_sets
        alpha = parameter_sets[0]
        mu_0 = 1
        residu = 0
        transfer = (y - self.func(x))

        for i in range(x.shape[1]):

            residu += (transfer[i] / (1 + self.Euclidean_distance(x[i, :], x[-1, :]))) ** 2

        for j in range(1, len(parameter_sets)):
            residu += (mu_0 * parameter_sets[j]) ** 2
        residu += (mu_0 * (alpha - 1)) ** 2

        return residu

    def run(self,y,x):
        plsq = minimize(self.residuals, self.parameter_sets ,args=(y, x))
        return plsq.x

x = np.array([[0.1,0.2],[0.3,0.4],[0.4, 0.5],[0.6, 0.7],[0.8,0.9],[0.9,1],[1,1.1]])
y = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
least_squares =  Least_squares()
print(least_squares.run(y,x))
```

```py
Error：TypeError: residuals() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

Question: All the def can work independently except `run`. Can someone help me to figure it out？

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: What are `x` and `y` in this case? What is `parameter_sets` and how is it a good choice for an initial guess?

Comment: Please update the title to something that explains the problem and can help future searchers find this post if they have a similar problem. The current title is meaningless because of how vague it is. You should also add more details about what your issue is. Currently, you just say that `run` doesn't work and show the error. Really, this is an error from `scipy.optimize.minimize` and you're confused about why it thinks there should be 3 positional arguments and what are the 4 arguments it is supposedly passing.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. This is my code below:

```py
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np


class Least_squares:
    def __init__(self):
        self.d = 2           # decision_demension
        self.parameter_sets = np.ones(6)

    def func(self, x, parameter_sets):
        alpha = parameter_sets[0]
        Phi = parameter_sets[1]
        T = 1
        for i in range(2, self.d + 2):
            Phi += x[:, i - 2]*parameter_sets[i]
        for j in range(self.d + 2, len(parameter_sets)):
            Phi += x[:, j - self.d - 2]*x[:, j - self.d - 2]*parameter_sets[j]

        Phi += alpha * T

        return Phi

    def Euclidean_distance(self, a, b):
        dis = 0
        for i in range(self.d):
            dis += (a[i] - b[i])**2
        return dis ** 0.5

    def residuals(self, parameter_sets, y, x):
        alpha = parameter_sets[0]
        mu_0 = 1
        residu = 0
        transfer = (y - self.func(x, parameter_sets))

        for i in range(x.shape[0]):  # Fix: iterate over rows, not columns
            residu += (transfer[i]/(1 + self.Euclidean_distance(x[i, :], x[-1, :])))**2

        for j in range(1, len(parameter_sets)):
            residu += (mu_0 * parameter_sets[j])**2
        residu += (mu_0 * (alpha - 1))**2

        return residu

    def run(self, y, x):
        plsq = minimize(self.residuals, self.parameter_sets, args=(y, x), method='BFGS')
        return plsq.x


x = np.array([[0.1, 0.2],
              [0.3, 0.4],
              [0.4, 0.5],
              [0.6, 0.7],
              [0.8, 0.9],
              [0.9, 1],
              [1, 1.1]])
y = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
least_squares = Least_squares()
print(least_squares.run(y, x))
```

Comment: This is not a sufficient answer for Stack Overflow. For this to be useful for future searchers, you should explain what the issue is, how to fix it, and edit the relevant code. Since most of the code remains the same, you should only focus on what needs to be changed.